# Using regular expression to match and replace

Tags: python, regex, python-re

There is a list of string A which is some how matching with another list of string B. I wanted to replace string A with list of matching string B using regular expression. However I am not getting the correct result.

The solution should be `A == ["Yogesh","Numita","Hero","Yogesh"]`.

```
import re

A = ["yogeshgovindan","TNumita","Herohonda","Yogeshkumar"]
B=["Yogesh","Numita","Hero"]

for i in A:
    for j in B:
        replaced=re.sub('i','j',i)
        
print(replaced)
```

Comment: Note `'i'` is the *string* "i" and has no connection to the *variable* `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one works to me:

```
lst=[]
for a in A:
    lst.append([b for b in B if b.lower() in a.lower()][0])
```

This returns element from list B if it is found at A list. It's necessary to compare lowercased words. The `[0]` is added for getting string instead of list from comprehension list.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working with the sample list. However when I increased the elements in the list then I am getting the error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Besides if my list is A = ["yogesh ovindan","TNumita","Herohonda","Yogesh umar"]
B=["Yogesh","Numita","Hero"] then the result is an empty list

Comment: Still works fine to me. Are you sure about the order of elements in brackets (e.g. in the if statement)? And be sure you defining list=[] before the for cycle. In the case it won't work, place here your code.

Answer (score 1):

If looping over `B`, you don't need a regular expression; you can simply use [membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in).

A regex might result in better performance, as membership testing will scan each string in `A` for every string in `B`, resulting in `O(len(A) * len(B) performance)`.

As long as the individual terms don't contain any metacharacters and can appear in any context, the simplest way to form the regex is to join the entries of `B` with the [alternation operation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
reTerms = re.compile('|'.join(B), re.I)
```

However, to be safe, the entries should first be escaped, in case any contains a metacharacter:

```
# map-based
reTerms = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, B)), re.I)
# comprehension-based
reTerms = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(b) for b in B]), re.I)
```

If there is any restrictions on the context the terms appear in, sub-patterns for the restrictions would need to be prepended and appended to the pattern. For example, if the terms must appear as full words:

```
reTerms = re.compile(f"\b(?:{'|'.join(map(re.escape, B))})\b", re.I)
```

This regex can be applied to each item of `A` to get the matching text:

```
replaced = [reTerms.search(name).group(0) for name in A]
# result: ['yogesh', 'Numita', 'Hero', 'Yogesh']
```

Since the terms in the regex are straight string matches, the content will be correct, but the case may not. This could be corrected by a normalization step, passing the matched text through a `dict`:

```
normed = {term.lower():term for term in B}

replaced = [normed[reTerms.search(name).group(0).lower()] for name in A]
# result: ['Yogesh', 'Numita', 'Hero', 'Yogesh']
```

One issue remains: what if an item of `A` doesn't match? Then `reTerms.search` returns `None`, which doesn't have a `group` attribute. If `None`-propagating attribute access is added to Python (such as suggested by [PEP 505](https://peps.python.org/pep-0505/)), this would be easily addressed by using such:

```
names = ["yogeshgovindan","TNumita","Herohonda","Yogeshkumar", "hrithikroshan"]
normed[None] = None
replaced = [normed[reTerms.search(name)?.group(0).lower()] for name in names]
```

In the absence of such a feature, there are various approaches, such as using a ternary expression and [walrus assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions). In the sample below, a list is used as a stand-in to provide a default value for the match:

```
import re

names = ["yogeshgovindan","TNumita","Herohonda","Yogeshkumar", "hrithikroshan"]
terms = ["Yogesh","Numita","Hero"]
normed = {term.lower():term for term in terms}
normed[''] = None

reTerms = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, terms)), re.I)

# index may need to be changed if `reTerms` includes any context
[normed[(reTerms.search(sentence) or [''])[0].lower()] for sentence in sentences]
```